# I´m studing for an exam, i need help! C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Well, i have to do this exercise and i don´t now how can show this array 2D by this way[This is the exercise:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7qbN.png)

This is what i have done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


const int MaxFila    = 8;
const int MaxColumna = 5;

void rellenarVector (int matriz[MaxFila][MaxColumna]);
void MostrarMatriz  (int matriz[MaxFila][MaxColumna]);

int main() {

    int matriz[MaxFila][MaxColumna];
    rellenarVector(matriz);
    MostrarMatriz(matriz);

    return 0;
}

void rellenarVector (int matriz[MaxFila][MaxColumna]){

    cout << "introduce los valores de la matriz: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < MaxFila; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < MaxColumna; j++){
            cin >> matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void MostrarMatriz (int matriz[MaxFila][MaxColumna]){

    int Filaux = 0, columaux = 0;

    for(int i = Filaux; i < MaxFila; i++){

        for(int j = columaux; j < MaxColumna; j++){
            cout << matriz[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Well my doubt is how to go through this matrix, because my question is how to make the change from adding to subtract rows and columns. I am a student of first of informatica and well I have some normal doubts when being rookie. Any help would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you mean by "adding to subtract rows and columns"?

Comment: You should provide a translation of the exercise.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Some programmer dude, i have to show the matrix like the photo of the post. i am from ceuta, spain, and my english is not good. Sorry about my post, i´m the worst on it.

Comment: This exercise must resolve by the easier way. I ask on my classroom group and one of my classmates say that i will use while into other while, but i don´t now how can i do like this way.

Comment: As I understand you have to implement one function so go recursive and handle turning on each function call, add and subtract.

Comment: Nah, to me it looks like printing numbers from array in order depending on shown spiral.

Comment: how can i do this function?

Comment: Simple maths, write down values of x and y coord, simplyfi it and you have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the indexes. Say, you will have `i` for the rows and `j` for the columns, `rows` rows and `columns` columns.

First, for the row `i=0`, you have to print all columns, from `j=0` to `columns-1`.

Next, for the `j=columns-1` column, you have to print all rows minus the first, from `i=1` to `rows-1`.

Next, for `i=rows-1`, print `j=columns-1` to `j=0`.

And so on.

```
//make sure to obtain columns and rows from to your matrix
int columns=5;
int rows=8;

int direction=1; //let say 1 is left to right (start direction), 2 is up to down, 3 is right to left and 4 is down to up
int i=0, j=0;

//set the limits where it must change direction
int minJ=0, maxJ=columns-1, minI=1, maxI=rows-1, totalElements=rows*columns;

for(int k=0;k<totalElements;k++) { //stop when all elements have been printed
    cout<<matriz[i][j]<<" ";

    //move one index based on the direction

    if(direction==1) {
        //check if direction must change, otherwise advance in this direction
        if(j==maxJ) {
            //now go down
            direction=2;
            //reduce the limits, because the next time its going in this direction, the last element will already have been printed
            maxJ--;
            //also move the pointer in the new direction so in the next loop it prints the next element
            i++;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    } else if(direction==2) {
        if(i==maxI) {
            //now go left
            direction=3;
            maxI--;
            j--;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    } else if(direction==3) {
        if(j==minJ) {
            //now go up
            direction=4;
            minJ++;
            i--;
        } else {
            j--;
        }
    } else if(direction==4) {
        if(i==minI) {
            //now go right again
            direction=1;
            minI++;
            j++;
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the way, so much thanks!